# When and why to use AF_UNIX, why work with the same machine

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.7, local

I started studying the `socket` library in **Python** for the first time, and I realized that there is a constant called `AF_UNIX` that does the same thing as `AF_INET` but it is faster and establishes connection only with the same machine and uses the system file instead of internet connection

but what I didn't understand is **why? why would i establish communication with my own machine? what use would that be and in what situation would it really be useful to use AF_UNIX?**

Comment: so two different applications on the same host can communicate with each other very fast.  For example uwsgi web gateway and a python flask server

Comment: @bauman.space: And they can communicate without any risk of an outside connection from the network bypassing the gateway by directly connecting to the service behind it.

Comment: yes, but you can bind uwsgi to the network card and  flask to localhost/127.0.0.1 solve that problem, it's just that unix socket is faster because you don't have the whole TCP stack in the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has many answers, I'll try to answer a few use cases for `AF_UNIX`:

1. You could use it to expose a private channel for other processes to communicate securely using files (since it'll respect the filesystem hierarchy and *nix permission model). PostgreSQL is known to expose a unix socket for it's `psql` cli to connect securely.
2. You could implement exchangeable communications using a socket protocol, as it's easy to move between `AF_INET` and `AF_UNIX` and expand it's communication throughout different hosts (redis and docker does this).
3. You could create a extendable and fast way for different processes and technologies to communicate without the device overhead `AF_INET` would include, even if you're using loopback interface.

The possibilities are actually limitless, as it includes a bit of personal preference. But the fact that `AF_UNIX` uses a similar specification as `AF_INET` makes it a powerful tool to extend communications between processes without having to rely on heavily different tools (FIFOs, shared mem, internal queues, files, to name a few).